# Working with global.js in nightwatch js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am writing some test in nightwatch and have a globals.js file which is literally exporting a js object below.

```
var self = module.exports = {
    environment: undefined,
    beforeEach: function (browser, done) {
        browser.execute(function(data) {
            return window.navigator.userAgent;
        }, [], function(result) {
            self.environment = result.value;
            console.log("Run against: " + self.environment);
            done();
        });
        console.log('the new env is', self.environment);
    },
};
```

Note : `console.log("Run against: " + self.environment);` prints my env value which is not undefined in this case. However. When ever i try to access environ from another file/class . It returns the default undefined despite the fact that i updated it previously. Example is from the test below.

```
module.exports = {
    tags: ['assetindex'],
    'visit': function(browser) {

        console.log('the environment is', browser.globals.environment);
        (/Chrome/.test(browser.globals.environment)) ?
            browser
                .page.assetindex().mobileVisit()
                .end()
        :
            browser
                .page.assetindex().desktopVisit()
                .end()
    }
};
```

`browser.globals.environment` always returned undefined here despite the fact that i changed it in my beforeEach function. Please how do i achieve this? What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `browser.globals` is a copy of `globals.js`. I would replace `self.environment` with `browser.globals.environment` in `beforeEach` :

```
module.exports = {
    environment: undefined,

    beforeEach: function (browser, done) {
        browser.execute(function(data) {
            return window.navigator.userAgent;
        }, [], function(result) {
            browser.globals.environment = result.value;
            console.log("Run against: " + browser.globals.environment);
            done();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: B . Is there any way i can archieve this in `before` not `beforeEach` . I noticed i do not need to repeat the same test all the time and can just skip with one before. I realise before receive a different param and browser is not one . Please how can i do that in before ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure you can do it before the beforeEach. You could skip the `browser.execute` in `beforeEach` if the `environment` is already defined.

Comment: oic, Can you please give me example with skipping ?. Do i return null or put the browser.exec in a if block ?

Comment: Sure: `if (browser.globals.environment) { done(); return; }`